# JMeter - Access TransactionController in Beanshell Listener

Tags: jmeter

I've created a BeanShell Listener element in my test plan which I use to collect SampleResult data for each HttpRequest and send to third party software. Presently there are four HttpRequests in my plan:

1. Get - Hit Login Page
2. Post - Submit data to Login Page
3. Get - Hit page to setup session
4. Get - Hit 'Home Page'

Steps 2 and 3 are related and ran sequentially so from a reporting perspective are essentially '1 step'. I've created a TransactionController around these two elements but my Listener script only appears to be able to retrieve the result data from the second of these two elements. Essentially I want my script to get the total time taken for these two steps for reporting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your scenario (using JMeter 2.8). Here is how my test plan looks like:

```
Thread Group
  HTTP Request 1
  Transaction Controller
    HTTP Request 2
    HTTP Request 3
  HTTP Request 4
  Beanshell Listener
```

My Beanshell Listener has row
`log.info(sampleResult.toString() + " - " + sampleResult.getLatency());`.

It logs (with omitted log info):

```
HTTP Request 1 - 143
HTTP Request 2 - 84
HTTP Request 3 - 83
Transaction Controller - 167
HTTP Request 4 - 93
```

Looks like it works